# Example of a non-polynomial function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)$ is negative for $x<0$ and positive for $x \ge 0$.

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

I have a bunch of polynomial functions example easily (e.g. $x^2$), but have trouble coming up with a non-polynomial function.

I was thinking of defining $f(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = e^{x}$ for $x \ge 0$. But it suffers the same problem as $g(x) = |x|$ because derivative does not exist at $x = 0$.

Is there any hint for this?

Comment: $f(x)=e^{-(1/x^2)}; f(0)=0$ if $x=0$

Comment: @Chilango This function is even (and differentiable), so $f'(0) = 0$ and in particular $f'(0)$ is not positive.

Comment: Yes i didnt see that you want it positive at 0 thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a theorem of [Darboux,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) a derivative has the *Intermediate Value Property*. So it cannot be positive at $0$ and negative somewhere else without being $0$ somewhere in between.

Comment: Actually I think you are correct. I would suppose the author of the book made a mistake.

Comment: Well, if we change the $x\ge 0$ to $x\gt 0$, then your $x^2$ works, as does the suggested $e^{x^2}$, and many others.

Answer (score 2):

What about? $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  $f(x)=e^{x^2}$

Comment: This function does not satisfy $f'(0) > 0$ as required.

Comment: I just checked the question again it does require that $f'(x)>0$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Oh then it is not possible as the derivative has to hit 0 at some point, as the other answerer posted above, sorry misread the question.